# Aplicativo fechando quando recebo recebo ligação / troco de tela

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um app android com a ajuda do Android Studio, o aplicativo é um menu com 4 webviews.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente. O meu problema é que, quando eu recebo uma ligação e o app esta aberto, assim que termino a chamada e desligo, o celular volta para a tela do Desktop, matando meu aplicativo.

Gostaria que, ao encerrar a ligação, o app voltasse direto para a última tela ativa do app. Mas não é só quando recebo chamadas, quando abro algum outro app pela barra do android junto com o meu app, ao fechar o outro aplitcativo, ele não volta para o meu, simplesmente volta para a tela Desktop.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


    import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
    import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
        public static Tracker tracker;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

            tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-45783691-7");
            tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
            tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
            tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
           // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo);


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            if(webView.canGoBack()){
                webView.goBack();
            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle("Fechar")
                        .setMessage("Tem certeza que deseja encerrar o aplicativo?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }

                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Não", null)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            Fragment fragment;

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                fragment = new SiteFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
                ft.commit();


            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                fragment = new ForumActivity();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
                ft.commit();

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
                fragment = new LojaActivity();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
                ft.commit();

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
                fragment = new ClassificadosActivity();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
                ft.commit();

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Eu estou usando o APP  para android. Baixe você também em: ");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            }
            else if (id == R.id.chat_mobile) {
                fragment = new ChatFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        }
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Coloque o código da tela que apresenta esse problema. Em especial, o `onCreate` e o `onResume`.

Comment: Eu inclui o código da MainActiv,  as outras são fragmentos da main.. O encerramento de quando atende ligações, ocorre tanto com o app aberto na Main ou em qualquer Fragment.  Lembrando que o APP funciona 100%. O único problema é o encerramento.

Comment: MArko, o snnipet é mais recomendado para códigos que podem ser simulados e renderizados aqui, como hmtl, css e javascript. Para outros códigos, use o `{}` para formatar.

Comment: É eu tinha tentando usar, mas toda vez que eu colava o código uma parte ficava de fora.. Mas agora deu certo. Obrigado.